# javascript - bluebird is not starting promises correctly

Tags: promise, bluebird

I am having a problem with [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) `concurreny`. Basically I want my promises to be fired one after an other. I found that this can be done using `bluebird`. This is my code:

```
var  getdep = Promise.promisify(
  function getdep(module, cb ) {
    console.log(module + " ...start ...")
    ls(module, function(data) {
      cb(null, data);
    });
  });

 Promise.all([0,1,2,3,].map(function(data){
   return getdep("uglify-js@2.4.24");
 }, {concurrency: 1}))
 .then(function(all){
   console.log(all);
 })
 .catch(function(err){
   console.log(err);
 });
```

What I respected is something like (`{concurrency: 1}`).

```
uglify-js@2.4.24 ...start ...
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
....
uglify-js@2.4.24 ...start ...
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
```

...
and so on

but what I am having is:

```
uglify-js@2.4.24 ...start ...
uglify-js@2.4.24 ...start ...
uglify-js@2.4.24 ...start ...
uglify-js@2.4.24 ...start ...
loading: uglify-js@2.4.24@latest
```

That means `bluebird` is starting all my promises at the same time.
Can you please tell me what is wrong in my code ? thanks

Comment: you have a typo) you set `concurrency` to `Array.map` instead `Promise.all`. And better to return something in each step of promise chain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Array#map not Promise.map

```
 Promise.all(
    [0,1,2,3,].map(function(data){
 //      array.map
         return getdep("uglify-js@2.4.24");
     }, {concurrency: 1}) // end of array.map 
 )
 .then(function(all){
   console.log(all);
 })
 .catch(function(err){
   console.log(err);
 });
```

Array.map doesn't understand the {concurrency:1} argument - it uses that as the `thisArg` for the callback

To use Promise.map, use Promise.map like this

```
 Promise.map([0,1,2,3,], function(data){
     return getdep("uglify-js@2.4.24");
 }, {concurrency: 1}))
 .then(function(all){
   console.log(all);
 })
 .catch(function(err){
   console.log(err);
 });
```